# Do Traversables really require to be traversed "left-to-right"?

Tags: haskell

I have an infinite structure like the following (using the [Stream](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/streams/3.0/doc/html/Data-Stream-Infinite.html) type from the [streams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streams) package):

```
data U x = U (Stream x) x (Stream x) deriving (Functor,Foldable)
```

I want to provide an instance of Traversable for it, like this:

```
instance Traversable U where
    traverse f (U lstream focus rstream) = 
        let pairs =  liftA unzip 
                   . sequenceA . fmap (traversepair f) 
                   $ zip lstream rstream 
            traversepair f (a,b) = (,) <$> f a <*> f b
            rebuild c (u,v) = U u c v
        in rebuild <$> f focus <*> pairs
```

The [documentation for Data.Traversable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Traversable.html) says that they represent the "class of data structures that can be traversed from left to right". But my definition does not traverse from left to right, it traverses *outwardly*. I had to define it that way to be able to lazily extract values on both sides after a [sequence](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Traversable.html#v%3asequence) operation involving the [Rand](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.8/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html#t%3aRand) monad.

Is it a valid definition nonetheless? I have noticed that the [Typeclassopedia entry for Traversable](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Traversable) doesn't say anything about "left-to-right", it only talks about "commuting two functors".

Comment: Infinite structures are not `Traversable`. There's no good `dist :: Stream (Maybe x) -> Maybe (Stream x)`. I'd say that traversal *defines* a notion of left-to-right: if that doesn't correspond to the textual left-to-right in a program, I usually wonder why. But your example is interesting. It relies on a laziness that not all applicatives possess. Hmm.

Comment: I would have been inclined to say there is no reason that an infinite structure cannot be traversable - but it does require a laziness that not all applicative functors. But so would an infinite list of course, which is traversable.

Also, there are lots of options for the specific dist function for maybe across stream that you mention, although traversable instances usually don't satisfy it. For example, if the first item is Nothing, the result is nothing, otherwise the result is Just the stream filtered of nothings.

Comment: Here is a gist with the full code: https://gist.github.com/4413623 I need to use "sequence" to aggregate monadic effects inside a comonad.

Comment: I forked the gist, introduced @SjoerdVisscher's correction in the first revision, and played with it a bit more in the revisions after it.

Comment: @DarkOtter Define filter for streams in a manner which ensures its productivity.

Comment: By that I assume you mean in a way in which it is guaranteed to terminate, or at least get each next item in a finite time. That is of course not possible to guarantee - there is no way to know how far you might have to look to find the next Just x value. But the same is true of filtering a normal list. e.g. `filter (4 ==) $ 4:(repeat 5)'.

Comment: @pigworker: I've taken to a different way of thinking about traversals. We use infinite traversals all the time. The real culprit here is that `Maybe` is strict in both sides of `(<*>)`, it isn't productive. The Maybe example fails because it needs an oracle for the halting problem, equality of streams is Pi_0^2 complete. But, you can reason perfectly well about infinite traversals if you stick to productive Applicatives and permit yourself only a finite number of reassociations to get to the next constructor. This is a pretty bad forum for this sort of discussion, though. ;)

Comment: About traversals of inifinite structures: http://comonad.com/reader/2022/internalized-guarded-recursion-for-equational-reasoning/ https://discourse.haskell.org/t/internalised-guarded-recursion-for-equational-reasoning/5207

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/17778) the laws should be:

1. `traverse Identity == Identity`
2. `traverse (Compose . fmap g . f) == Compose . fmap (traverse g) . traverse f`

These 2 laws ensure that each element in the traversed structure is traversed exactly once. It does not matter in which order. You could even say that a `Traversable` instance *defines* what left-to-right means for that particular datatype.

There are two other requirements in the documentation:

- In the `Functor` instance, `fmap` should be equivalent to traversal with
  the identity applicative functor (`fmapDefault`).
- In the `Foldable` instance, `foldMap` should be equivalent to traversal with a constant applicative functor (`foldMapDefault`).

In your above code, you break the second requirement, because you're deriving `Foldable`, which will visit the elements in a different order than your `Traversable` instance. Creating your own instance for `Foldable` with `foldMapDefault` fixes that.

By the way, `sequenceA . fmap (traversepair f)` is `traverse (traversepair f)`.

Comment: I'd also introduce `data Pair a = Pair a a` here. It makes the code a bit more generic.

Comment: I'd probably write is as `traverse f (U lstream focus rstream) = (\c (unzip -> (u,v)) -> U u c v) <$> f focus <*> traverse (both f) (zip lstream rstream)`, using `ViewPatterns`, and `both` from the `lens` package.

Comment: `both` seems nice. I ended up with `traverse f (U p x q) = (\c (Pair u v) -> U u c v) <$> f x <*> (fmap getCompose . traverse f . Compose) (Pair p q)`, so `Data.Functor.Compose` takes care of it.

Comment: `fmap getCompose . traverse f . Compose` is the same as `traverse (traverse f)`, which does not do the zipping. You can use `Compose`, because the `Applicative` instance of `Stream` does the zipping, something like `getCompose (traverse (Compose . traverse f) (Pair p q))`, but you'd still need to unzip.

Comment: I think I forgot to bracket it in `sequenceA`'s, which would do the zipping and unzipping.